# Is it possible to coonect the power to the sata power slot on a PCIE card from HPE ProLiant DL360p Gen8 server?

Tags: electrical-power, sata, hpe

This is my first server and I never had one before...

I recently need to use USB 3.0 for external HDD but there is none on this server, all USB 2.0. So I bought a "3 Ports USB 3.0 with 1Gbps Gigabit Ethernet Controller PCIe Expansion Card":
https://www.amazon.com.au/gp/product/B089JYVHYR/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I didn't know it requires power...which seems to be sata power slot..
[image]
It seems to need 5v input.

I looked at the manual: https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1022077952.pdf
And I am still not sure if I can do that.

All I can see is that on the motherboard, there is a Optical SATA connector. I believe it is mini power sata? I am thinking maybe I can just buy a adapter mini power sata to sata that will do it? But I don't know which one to buy.
Will something like this work?
https://www.amazon.com.au/Pin-Slimline-SATA-Power-Cable/dp/B0056OA8ZW

There is also a mysterious slot as below, can this be used?
[image]
[image]

If these don't work, is there any other way...?

Appreciate any helps...

Answer (score 1):

That controller card was designed for a desktop machine, where it is normal to have a few spare SATA power cables from the PSU.

Nothing wrong with using it in a server, but because disks are typically connected with a backplane PCB instead of cables, and spare cables are removed as they impede airflow, you won't find a SATA power cable in your server.

If you're lucky, your PSU has some extra ports, and all you need is a cable that, if you're extra lucky, included in the box of spare parts.

Basically, attaching USB disks to servers is a rather uncommon thing, because you don't want people wandering around your datacenter spreading dust that will collect in fans, causing even more people to wander around in the datacenter while replacing broken fans.